# How to configure DNS records for mail server not also registered as name server

Tags: dns, mail-server

I have a single server (server1.host.com single static ip address 12.34.56.78) setup as follows:

1.apache (websites)

- client1.com,
- client2.com
- client3.com

2.postfix/dovecot (SMTP and IMAP)

- info@client1.com
- info@client2.com
- info@client3.com

**I am not using this system as a registered dns server, all domains are obtaining dns from their own registrars.**

Clients are complaining about having to use the servers own hostname in their mx records

server1.host.com
A record points to ip address 12.34.56.78

Instead, they want to be able to use

mail.client1.com

mail.client2.com

mail.client3.com

the reason for this change is because mail client apps like outlook grumble profusely when the hostname is different from the client1.com domain. Clients are having problems setting up apps on pc's and mobile phones...its a real nightmare.

Also, lots of SSL errors keep popping up because the SSL certificate belongs to host.com (the servers own domain) instead of client1.com

Is it possible to do this if server1.host.com is not a registered dns server?

They do not want to have to purchase their own ip addresses

IF so, exactly what dns records are needed to do this at client's registrar?

Comment: How is DNS registrar configuration related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Why would you ask that question? Ubuntu O/S is used for webhosting and mail platforms all the time, as are Centos, Debian etc. Is there no expertise on this forum for setting up servers for hosting and email and configuring dns? The registrar component of the question is irrelevant. It simply outlines the server itself is not being used for public dns resolution

Comment: I was trying to understand the question, that's all..